# Running logo program (ucblogo) in Emacs

Tags: package, major-mode

I am trying to run logo programs (ucblogo version 5.5) on my emacs in Debian Linux (26.1). There is a currently a mode for it ( https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LogoMode ). I followed the instructions on the wiki page and configured my `init.el` file such as:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/logo")
(autoload 'logo-mode "logo")
(setq auto-mode-alist (append '(("\\.lgo?$" . logo-mode)) auto-mode-alist))
(setq logo-binary-name "/usr/bin/logo")
(setq logo-tutorial-path "~/.emacs.d/logo/")
(setq logo-help-path "~/.emacs.d/logo/helpfiles/")
(setq logo-info-file "~/.emacs.d/logo/docs/ucblogo.info")
```

I was able to see menu items for ucblogo on Emacs but when I click on the item "Run Logo Other Frame", it is not running logo interpreter and I get an error:

```
comint-mode: Symbol’s function definition is void: make-local-hook
```

I tried with different version of ucblogo (6.0). The logo interpreter starts but  my emacs freezes and I am not able to edit my logo buffer.